# How to load post with CLLocation

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I am building an iphone app the uses AFNetworking to GET and POST data to a rails-backed server.
Everything is working fine, but now I am trying to pass lat/lng parameters so that I load nearby posts. I am pretty sure I set it up correctly- the heroku logs show a get request made with lat/lng- but the problem I am having is a more basic one. In my indexViewController, in the **viewDidLoad** method I try to call

```
[self loadPosts]
```

But I get into trouble because, below that, when I define loadPosts and call the fetchNearbyPosts method, I need to call a CLLocation as part of its implementation- which causes an undeclared identifier error. I can fix that by declaring:

```
loadPosts:(CLLocation *)location {
```

But then, in viewDidLoad, when I change [self loadPosts:(CLLocation *)location];
that line now gets an undeclared identifier error for 'location'. 
So I am going in circles.

My fetchNearbyPosts method is like so:

```
+ (void)fetchNearbyPosts:(CLLocation *)location
          withBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"lat": @(location.coordinate.latitude),
                                 @"lng": @(location.coordinate.longitude)
                                 };

    [[APIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"/posts" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (operation.response.statusCode ==200) {
        NSArray *posts = [Post postsWithJSON:responseObject];
        completionBlock(posts, nil);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Recieved an HTTP %d: %@", operation.response.statusCode, responseObject);
            completionBlock(nil, nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        completionBlock(nil, error);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

And my full loadPosts method is:

```
- (void)loadPosts:(CLLocation *)location {
    [Post fetchNearbyPosts:location withBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {
        if (posts) {
            NSLog(@"Recieved %d posts", posts.count);
            self.posts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:posts];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
        } else {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR"
                                        message:@"Couldn't fetch the posts."
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }];
}
```

I think this is pretty basic- but how does one go about calling loadPosts in ViewDidLoad with a CLLocation?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you need to get your current location to pass it as a parametr for your **- (void)loadPosts:(CLLocation *)location** method, which will be called in your **viewDidLoad**

add this method to your view controller:

```
-(CLLocation) getLocation{
    CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation * location = [locationManager location];
    return location;
 }
```

and then, in your **viewDidLoad** call this

```
[self loadPosts: [self getLocation]];
```

Comment: Just because you tell it to startUpdatingLocation does not mean that a location will be available immediately. I would suggest revising to actually implement the delegate and make the delegate method `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` handle calling `[self loadPosts];` to guarantee that a valid location is found.